# Question on a proof of Dynkin's $\lambda-\pi$ theorem

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to understand a specific proof of Dynkin's $\lambda-\pi$ thereom stating that a collection $F$ on $\Omega$ is a $\sigma$-algebra if and only if it is both a $\pi$-system and $\lambda$-system.

I understood that if $F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra then it is both a $\pi$-system and $\lambda$-system, but I have some difficulty to understand proof of the converse, i.e., if $F$ is both $\lambda$ and $\pi$ system, then it is a $\sigma$-algebra.

To show the converse statement, the proof I am interested shows that $F$ is closed under countable union, i.e., $$\text{if } A_1,A_2,\ldots\in F, \text{ then } \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\in F.$$
For this purpose, it defines $B_1 = A_1$ and $B_{i+1} = A_{i+1}\setminus\bigcup_{n=1}^iA_n$, where $
B_{i+1} = A_{i+1} \cap\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^i A_n^c\right),
$
then, it uses the following facts and concludes.

1. The finite intersection $B_{i+1} = A_{i+1} \cap\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^i A_n^c\right)$ is in $\pi$-system.
2. $B_i$'s are disjoint so their countable union $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i  = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_i $ in $\lambda$-system.

What I could not understand is that as index $i$ in the union goes to infinity, $B_i$ includes countable (infinite) intersection of $A_i^c$, but countable intersection is not included in $\pi$-systems which have only finite intersection. So, how do we know that $B_i$'s are indeed in $F$?

In general, I could not get that how can we obtain countable intersection property of $\sigma$-algebra by using complement, countable union of disjoint sets, and finite intersection properties of $\lambda$ and $\pi$ system?

Answer (score 1):

You never get an infinite intersection here. By definition, for a specific $i\geq 1$ we have $B_{i+1}=A_{i+1}\cap (\cap_{n=1}^i A_n^c)$. So we only have a **finite** intersection here, and hence $B_{i+1}$ does belong to this $\lambda$-system. There is no $i$ for which the intersection will be infinite.

Now, since the sets $B_i$ are pairwise disjoint their union also belongs to the $\lambda$-system.